# Annihilator in dual vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $y(x) = x_1 +x_2 + x_3 = 0$ whenever $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a vector in $\mathbb C^3$, then $y$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb C^3$; find a basis of the subspace consisting of all those vectors $x$ for which $[x,y]=0$

Please, help. I don't know how to start

Comment: What's $[x,y]$?

Comment: that's function of y on x. Old notation: y(x) = 0

Comment: Is $[x,y]$ simply $y(x)$ for a vector $x$? Do you know all of the necessary definitions?  Do you know how to find the kernel (aka null space) of a linear transformation?

Comment: I have to choose a base first, let say a1(1,0,0); a2(0,1,0); a3(0,0,1). Then, assign y(a1) =alpha; y(a2) =beta, y(a3) = gamma.then I will have [x,y] = [x1,y]+[x2,y]+[x3,y] =0. However, I don't see the link between the terms.:(

Comment: You seem to be on the wrong track here.  What do you think they mean by the subspace of all vectors for which $[x,y] = 0$?  How many dimensions should the subspace of vectors for which $[x,y] = 0$ be?

Comment: I know that is annihilator, y(x) =x1+x2+x3=0, therefore x1= -x2-x3.So, I have 2 free x2, x3, the null space has (-x2-x3,x2,x3)is a base or (x2(-1,1,0), x3(-1,0,1) ) . does it work now?

Comment: Well, let's just get the language right.  The set $\{(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)\}$ forms a basis of the nullspace of $y$, and thus is a basis of the subspace of vectors $x$ such that $[y,x] = 0$